# Outlook 2016 - How to display multiple mailboxes in a single pane?

Tags: windows, email, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, mailbox

I'm working with Outlook 2016 and I'd like to display multiple mailboxes (.pst or .ost) simultaneously on the left pane. I have set up for a user multiple profiles attached to different mailboxes.

When the user starts the Outlook client it prompts to select a profile and the mailbox, and only this mailbox, is loaded and displays on left pane.

Is there a way to display all mailboxes in left pane? I appreciate any guidance. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Instead of working with multiple profiles, use one profile, and add all mailboxes to it. When you setup a mailbox, there is this button `add another mailbox`.

This should've told you how to do it.

But if you go to your profiles, edit one profile, then go to mailboxes, there's a button to add another too.

Comment: Where do you do this? Are you talking about Account Settings, email tab? How do I add multiple mailboxes to one profile? Thanks.

Comment: Account settings is indeed one way to go. Alternatively Control Panel->Mail, which is where you'll find your profiles too.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have all of the email in the actual mailboxes on the server (so you don't have to haunt down all the *.PST files)

next go to control panel in Windows and find Mail:
[image]

next delete all of the profiles, except your main one

Start Outlook 2016 again, this time you will not be prompted to select a . profile

From within Outlook go to the Account settings and you see a button Add account (under the existing account name) - use that to add multiple account:
[image]

Comment: You can usually only configure exchange mailboxes with outlook closed. I would therefor do the setup from the control panel applet.